# Joomla Configuration.php how do i update class variables using function and assign them

Tags: php, oop, joomla

I need help in updating the `$host`, `$user`, `$password` and `$db` variables using a function inside this class.

So basically do some work inside a function then update that variables' value and have it return the output.

I can update `$this->user` for example and echo the output. However I cannot update the class variable `$user` with it.

```html
<?php
class JConfig {
 public $offline = '0';
 public $offline_message = 'This site is down for maintenance.<br />Please check back again soon.';
 public $display_offline_message = '1';
 public $offline_image = '';
 public $sitename = '';
 public $editor = 'tinymce';
 public $captcha = '0';
 public $list_limit = '20';
 public $access = '1';
 public $debug = '0';
 public $debug_lang = '0';
 public $dbtype = 'mysqli';
  public $host = '';
  public $user = '';
 public $password = '';
 public $db = '';
  public $dbprefix = 'i1jud_';
 public $live_site = '';
 public $secret = '';
 public $gzip = '0';
 public $error_reporting = 'default';
 public $helpurl = 'https://help.joomla.org/proxy/index.php?keyref=Help{major}{minor}:{keyref}';
 public $ftp_host = '';
 public $ftp_port = '';
 public $ftp_user = '';
 public $ftp_pass = '';
 public $ftp_root = '';
 public $ftp_enable = '0';
 public $offset = 'UTC';
 public $mailonline = '1';
 public $mailer = 'mail';
 public $mailfrom = '';
 public $fromname = '';
 public $sendmail = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
 public $smtpauth = '0';
 public $smtpuser = '';
 public $smtppass = '';
 public $smtphost = 'localhost';
 public $smtpsecure = 'none';
 public $smtpport = '25';
 public $caching = '0';
 public $cache_handler = 'file';
 public $cachetime = '15';
 public $cache_platformprefix = '0';
 public $MetaDesc = '';
 public $MetaKeys = '';
 public $MetaTitle = '1';
 public $MetaAuthor = '1';
 public $MetaVersion = '0';
 public $robots = '';
 public $sef = '1';
 public $sef_rewrite = '0';
 public $sef_suffix = '0';
 public $unicodeslugs = '0';
 public $feed_limit = '10';
 public $feed_email = 'none';
  public $log_path = '';
 public $tmp_path = '';
 public $lifetime = '15';
 public $session_handler = 'database';
 
}
```

```html
<?php
class updates
{
    public $user;
    function __construct(){
     $this->user = "user";
    }

    function username()
    {
         return $this->user = "new_user";
    }
    
     
}

$updates = new updates();
echo $updates->username();

?>
```

Comment: Provide a minimal reproducable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create three methods username, password, db.

Use constructor, update variables with result from methods. Works.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at plugins and pluginevents

https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User

Comment: literally no help at all.

Comment: It is when you want to modify the JUser object

Comment: You could use a plugin to modify the configuration object but you would have to use a system event not a user event. The configuration object is created very early on in the stack since you can't even know what template to use without it not to mention start a session etc.

Answer (score 0):

The variables in configuration.php that you mention are referring to the database name, database user, and database password   not a joomla user.   This has nothing to do with the JUser object and you would never want to change them unless you are moving your site.   That is, this is configuration for your site as a whole.

Why don't you start by  explaining what it is you are trying to accomplish by changing the user. For example are you trying to write a CLI script to do an install or to facilitate moving a site from one database to another database?

Comment: I am trying to start off with the initial values these variables have, add a couple of functions to update them and then assign the value from these functions back to these variables

Comment: Because you want to change to a different database ?  These values are in the configuration object.  So you would need to modify the configuration object.

Comment: its ok I found a solution. I don't need to modify any object. I'm not working directly with Joomla. I want to work directly inside the configuration.php file and get and update the variables.

Comment: Well Joomla has methods for that, but in general you will be taking down the site if you save any changes in configuration. Joomla handles that in com_config but that file is only modifiable by the owner.